# ggplot legend not working with scale_colour_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I know an identical question has been asked earlier. [ggplot legend - scale_colour_manual not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703853/ggplot-legend-scale-colour-manual-not-working)

But the question involves a somewhat complicated dataset than what I have here and the answer suggests restructuring data and then works with restructured data. But the problem persists even with simple data as I have below and I can't solve it. So please don't mark it as duplicate.

The problem: when using `scale_colour_manual` in ggplot2, the legend is not showing.

```
p <- data.frame(a = runif(10, 1, 2))
ggplot(data=p, aes(x=a)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(p$a), colour="mea")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(p$a), colour="med")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Statistic",
                      values=c("med"= "red", "mea"="green"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `geom_vline` currently defaults to `show_guide = FALSE`, so if you want a legend you'll need to change that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `show_guide=TRUE` in `geom_vline` (defaults to `FALSE`):

```
p <- data.frame(a = runif(10, 1, 2))
ggplot(data=p, aes(x=a)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(a), colour="mea"), show_guide=TRUE) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(a), colour="med"), show_guide=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Statistic",
                      values=c("med"= "red", "mea"="green"))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Ah, thanks! It's so simple. I wonder why the other question required an involved answer.

Comment: and use `mean(a)` inside `aes()`, instead of `mean(p$a)`

Answer (score 0):

To update [the answer of rcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33768687/18204352), `show_guide` has now been deprecated. You should now use: `show.legend = TRUE`.