# create correct legend for geom_point with different colors and shapes; data comes from two variables with different levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I already googled a lot on this problem, but none of the suggested solutions worked:

The plot shows actual and expected values for each subject on four sessions ('sitz' 1 to 4). The actual value and the expected value come from two different variables, actual value has three levels 'cont', 'treat and 'other', expected value has two levels:'cont' and 'treat'.

The actual value is depicted by a filled black circle and the expected one by an unfilled blue circle.

The problem: I don't find any method so that my legend is printed correctly. The best I could get was a black and filled and a blue and filled button, but the blue one shouldn't be filled. 
Here's the data and code:

````
    df <- structure(list(vp = c(2, 5, 15, 28, 32, 2, 18, 7, 28, 16, 24, 
                            6, 16, 22, 25, 26, 28, 14, 4, 8, 15, 38, 21, 29, 26, 21, 21, 
                            12, 11, 23), sitz = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
                                                            2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                            1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
                     GROUP = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("cont", "treat"), class = "factor"), 
                     img_50group = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                               3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("cont", "other", 
                                                                                       "treat"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame") 

ggplot(df, aes(x = sitz, y = img_50group)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = sitz, y = img_50group, color = "black", shape = 16), size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = sitz, y = GROUP, color = "darkblue", shape = 1), size = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~vp) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Strategies", labels = c("Actual", "Expected"), values=c("black", "darkblue")) + 
  scale_shape_identity(name="Strategies", labels = c("Actual", "Expected"), breaks =c("black", "darkblue"), guide = "legend") ```
````

Comment: The problem is you've plotted two separate `geom_point()`, each with a manually defined color. To use legends, you need to convert the data to long format so you have one variable to plot as points, and plot them with one `geom_point(aes(color = variablename))`. Questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703853/ggplot-legend-scale-colour-manual-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713919/two-geom-points-add-a-legend?rq=1) are similar to yours and could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should melt you data and then use `color`, `shape`, and `size` as aesthetics in the `aes()` call in `geom_point()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(vp = c(2, 5, 15, 28, 32, 2, 18, 7, 28, 16, 24, 
                            6, 16, 22, 25, 26, 28, 14, 4, 8, 15, 38, 21, 29, 26, 21, 21, 
                            12, 11, 23), sitz = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
                                                            2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                            1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
                     GROUP = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("cont", "treat"), class = "factor"), 
                     img_50group = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                               3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("cont", "other", 
                                                                                       "treat"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")

# Melt the data frame and use factors to preserve the order in the original graph
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(-vp, -sitz)) %>% 
  mutate(value = fct_relevel(value, "cont", "other", "treat"),
         name = factor(name, levels = c("img_50group", "GROUP")))

ggplot(df, aes(x = sitz, y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = sitz, y = value, color = name, shape = name, size = name)) +
  facet_wrap(~vp) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Strategies", 
                      labels = c("Actual", "Expected"), 
                      values=c("black", "darkblue")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="Strategies", 
                     labels = c("Actual", "Expected"),
                     values = c(16, 1)) + 
  scale_size_manual(name ="Strategies", 
                    labels = c("Actual", "Expected"), 
                    values = c(2, 5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>