# Legend in multiple line graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, linegraph

I am quite new to R and am attempting to plot three time series lines simultaneously in one graph (using different colors) making use of ggplot2. And I would like to add legend for the three lines but cannot produce the legend for the graph. Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Code

```r
ggplot ggplot(vn, aes(x=date)) + `ggplot enter code here`
      geom_line(aes(y = newcase),size=1, color="red") + 
      geom_line(aes(y = recovered),color="blue", size=1)+ 
      geom_line(aes(y = confirmed), color="green", linetype="solid", size=1)+
      xlab("Date")+
      ylab("People")+
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d/%m")
```

Data

```
Date        confirmed  recovered   newcase
2020-03-15  56  16  0
2020-03-16  61  16  4
2020-03-17  66  16  3
2020-03-18  75  16  7
```

Comment: The problem is you've plotted three separate `geom_line()`, each with a manually defined color. To use legends, you need to convert the data to long format (`tidyr::pivot_longer()` can do this!) so you have one variable to plot, and plot them with one geom_line(aes(color = variablename)). Questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703853/ggplot-legend-scale-colour-manual-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713919/two-geom-points-add-a-legend?rq=1) are similar to yours and could help.

Comment: you suggestion are really helpful so my problem solved. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to reshape your dataframe first using for example `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols = confirmed:newcase, names_to = "Cases", values_to = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ymd(Date), y = values, color = Cases))+
  geom_line()++
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("People")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d/%m")
```

With your example, it gives something like that:

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**reproducible example**

```r
data <- data.frame(Date = c("2020-03-15","2020-03-16","2020-03-17","2020-03-18"),
                   confirmed = c(56,61,66,75),
                   recovered = c(16,16,16,16),
                   newcase = c(0,4,3,7))
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, and thanks your help I can solve the problem now. Thank you so much for your kindly help